# reset defaults of \longtable

Tags: longtable

I read here that I can stretch out \longtable to fill the width of the page like this:

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l r@{}}
```

How do I reset to defaults later in the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\setlength\LTleft{\fill}
\setlength\LTright{\fill}
```

will reset the default centering or you could leave them as they are and use an explicit `[c]` which will set left and right to `\fill` for the specific table.

Comment: perfect.  thank you.

Comment: @R. B. Jawad If you think it's perfect, then you may accept the answer (tick left side of the answer)